# preg replace not producing expected results

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

how to change alt with preg replace? 
i just have write this code and semms not work.

```
$zmieniamy = get_content();
$slowokluczowe[0] = '1';
$slowokluczowe[1] = '2';
$slowokluczowe[2] = '2';
$slowokluczowe[3] = '3';
$slowokluczowe[4] = '4';
$k = array_rand($slowokluczowe);

echo preg_replace('/alt="(.*?)"/', $slowokluczowe[$k], $zmieniamy);
```

Any tips? :)

Comment: Tip1: explain where is the `alt` that you wish to replace

Comment: its inside get_content()

Comment: strange title then

Comment: get_content return html content witn text and images. I need to change alts in this content

Comment: Tip2: Instead of it does not work, can you tell what you expect and what you obtain instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have something strange going on with your array keys there. Namely:
`$k = array_rand($slowokluczowe);`
followed by :
`$slowokluczowe[$k]`

$k is already a random array value (and a string). Why use it as a key again (on a numerically indexed array)?

```
$zmieniamy = get_content();
$slowokluczowe[0] = '1';
$slowokluczowe[1] = '2';
$slowokluczowe[2] = '2';
$slowokluczowe[3] = '3';
$slowokluczowe[4] = '4';
$k = array_rand($slowokluczowe);

echo preg_replace('/alt="(.*?)"/', $k, $zmieniamy);
```

Comment: @Freshview dev-1 Tip2: mark this answer as accepted or explain why it is not what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer from @Ben Hillier.

I assume you want to keep the "alt", so this is the adapted `preg_replace()`

```
$zmieniamy = '<img src="src" alt="alt">';
$slowokluczowe[0] = '1';
$slowokluczowe[1] = '2';
$slowokluczowe[2] = '2';
$slowokluczowe[3] = '3';
$slowokluczowe[4] = '4';
$k = array_rand($slowokluczowe);

echo preg_replace('/alt="(.*?)"/', 'alt="'. $k .'"', $zmieniamy); // <img src="src" alt="2">
```